# How to use GUID as ID in Service Stack Redis client?

Tags: servicestack, servicestack.redis

How can I use a `GUID` or `UUID` for an object ID using `Service Stack`'s `Redis` client?

I'm still going through Pluralsight tutorials on `Service Stack` and `Redis` and I'm getting worried.  One of the requirements from my client is that the key of every object is a `UUID` (basically a Guid using `ToString("N")`).  I'm worried because the only `GetBy` method I can see  on the `RedisClient` uses an `int`.  Not only would an int allow too few objects, it would also not accomplish the task of using an UUID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely, the objects in your example inherit from `IHasId<string>`.  The interface defines that you do have an `Id` field and its data type.  This is what allows ServiceStack to find your objects by `Id`.  This also explains why you are seeing them stuff the field by using `ToString("N")` on the `Guid`.

As for Redis, think of it as any other dictionary using a key/value pair.  While there are recommended conventions out there for it, Redis should not care what the actual key is.  As long as your application supplies the correct key to Redis, even if that key is a `Guid`, you will receive the object requested.  ServiceStack will take care of the rest.